# Need clarification on the meaning of an algebraic term

Tags: real-analysis

If I have an expression of the form sqrt(3n^3+2n) is that one **single** term or is that two **separate** terms, with one being 3n^3 and the other being 2n?

Also if I have n2^n is this one term or two separate terms so if I divide by the fastest growing term in an expression and this happen to be it would I treat this as one term or two separate terms of n and 2^n.

Comment: I think sqrt(3n^3+2n) is a single term, similarly n2^n is also one term .

Answer (score 4):

The term *term* normally refers to an additive component, i.e., *terms* are separated by + signs. Looking at $\sqrt{3n^3 + 2n}$, this expression consists of a *single* term - there are no + signs at the top level. However, the expression $3n^3 + 2n$ consists of *two* terms - $3n^3$ and $2n$. Multiplicative components are referred to as $factors$. So, the term $n2^n$ consists of the *two* factors $n$ and $2^n$.

Comment: Not true, "term" is also used for for arguments of products as well as other *operations*. The meaning depends on the context

Comment: @BillDubuque Ok, that's true: term is also used generically. Still, I wouldn't say that the term $n2^n$ consists of two terms, but I would say that the expression $n2^n$ consists of two terms. So, indeed, context dependent.

Comment: Yes, e.g. in the polynomial $\,x^2 + 2\cdot 3\,$ we have the constant term $\,2\cdot 3\,$ but as a prime factorization $\,2\cdot 3\,$ has two terms.